# What is a better design if two subclasses have the same method?

Tags: oop

Just as an example, if `House` is the base class, and `Colonial` is a subclass of `House`, and Colonial has a method that is `goUpstairs`.  There is another class called `Mansion` which is also a subclass of `House`, and `Mansion` has a method `useElevator` (say a mansion can have many floors, such as 1 to 35).

Should things start out this way?  Or what if after 6 months, there need to be a new class `Duplex` which is a subclass of `House`, and also requires a method `goUpstairs`?  If we duplicate the `goUpstairs` code in `Colonial` and `Duplex`, then it is not so DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  Should the classes be designed different initially?  Or should be it designed differently only after the 6 months and how should it be changed?

Comment: The "house" object should never have methods like "goUpstairs". Think about it, how many houses have you ever seen traveling upstairs (or anywhere). `goUpstairs` is something you'd put in a "resident" object (person, dog, robot, whatever).

Comment: good point... maybe it could have been: `Animal` as superclass, and then `Bird`, `Fish` as subclasses.  So there is `fly` for `Bird` and `swim` for `Fish`, and 6 months later, there is a new subclass `Dog` that also should have a method `swim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to build such an inheritance tree. As you stated it come to a permutational explosion

Try using "interfaces"

In java

```
public abstract class House {
 ...
}

public interface HasStairs {
    public boolean putUpstairs (Thing x);
    public boolean putDownstairs (Thing x);
}

public interface HasElevator {
    public boolean putUp (Thing x);
    public boolean putDown (Thing x);
    public boolean putTo (Thing x, Floor pFloor);
}

public MyHouseA extends House {}

public MyHouseB extends House implements HasStairs {}

public MyHouseC extends House implements HasElevator {}

public MyHouseD extends House implements HasStairs, HasElevator {}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the house is a complete (Not Abstract) class then it should only have the functionality common in ALL of it's subclasses. If you want to have multiple classes have similar functions that aren't common to all the houses you could have multiple subclasses.

```
Public House ...

Public MultiLevelHouse extends House {
    public void goUpstairs() ...

Public Duplex extends MultiLevelHouse {
   ...

Public Colonial extends MutliLevelHouse {
   ...

Public Mansion extends MutliLevelHouse {
    //Override goUpstairs to use useEvalator if you want 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in a case like this, let's think a bit about the semantics.

- A house *has* stairs.
- A house *has an* elevator.

So, thinking like this, we will naturally arrive at *composition*.

Rather than put the methods for going up in the house itself, think of the house as a container for components. A mansion could exist without an elevator too.

So, you implement an `Elevator` class and a `Stairs` class (or maybe `Escalator`). If they share some code, or methods such as `goUp` or `goDown`, you could  have some interface or base class like `IVerticalTransport` or whatever.

Continuing with this train of thought, you would also have a `Floor` object. An `IVerticalTransport` would connect one or more `Floor`s, which in turn would be contained in a `House`.

Expanding this slightly to again include the Mansion and Duplex concepts you mentioned, it would probably make sense to have a `HouseFactory`. A `HouseFactory` would have methods to configure `House`s with specific settings.

- `HouseFactory.getMansion()` would return a `House` with 4 `Floor`s and several `Stair`s
- `HouseFactory.getDuplex()` would return a `House` with 10 `Floor`s  and two `Elevator`s
- etc.

I could go on and on with this really... :D

Comment: would `getMansion` also return a house with the appropriate method `useElevator` while `getDuplex` returns a house but is without `useElevator`?

Comment: The house would not include methods to directly act on such I think. Rather, you would have a method on it to return certain types of components. For example, you could have something like `House.getComponents(IVerticalTransport)`, which you would then iterate to find the one you wish to use. You could alternatively have a more specific getter, for example `getTransport(Floor a, Floor b)` which would return a transport between floors a and b. You could use the output from such getters to determine whether certain actions are possible or not, and to perform them.